# How to use nested filters in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement custom filter over an array of objects.

```
    let obj = [{
         flag: true
         note: "asdasd"
         id: "we"
         name: "tt1"
         list: [{
            "id" : 1,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
            },
            {
            "id" : 2,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
         }] 
    },
{
         flag: false
         note: "asdasd"
         id: "we"
         name: "tt1"
         list: [{
            "id" : 1,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
            },
            {
            "id" : 2,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
         }] 
    }
      ]
```

when user search for id = 1, i want the out put like

```
[{
     flag: true
     note: "asdasd"
     id: "we"
     name: "tt1"
     list: [{
        "id" : 1,
        "detail" : "asdasda"
        }] 
}]
```

The search will be done first over the flag === true then on id for those object where flag is true.

My code for pipe is as follows

@Pipe({
  name: 'pipe'
})

```
export class PipeNew implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, search: any): any {

    let filteredArray = value
      .filter((element) => {
        if (element.flag)
          return element ;
      })
      .filter((element) =>
        element.list.some(listObj => (listObj.id.indexOf(search) > -1)))
      .map((element) => {
        let newElt = Object.assign({}, element);
        return  newElt.list.filter(obj => (obj.id.indexOf(search) > -1))
      });

      return filteredArray;
  }
}
```

But i am only getting the out put as below

```
[{
        "id" : 1,
        "detail" : "asdasda"
        }]
```

Expected

```
[{
     flag: true
     note: "asdasd"
     id: "we"
     name: "tt1"
     list: [{
        "id" : 1,
        "detail" : "asdasda"
        }] 
}]
```

Please help Thanks ;)

Comment: I think you don't need a filter at this line `return  newElt.list.filter(obj => (obj.id.indexOf(search) > -1))`, just return the newElt like `return newElt`

Comment: You have already filtered the results before mapping

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are already filtering the results on list id before mapping so you don't need to filter on the line where you are returning. Change it like

```
let filteredArray = value.filter((element) => {
    if (element.flag){
        return element.list.filter((item)=> {
            return item.id.indexOf(search) > -1;
        });
      }
  }).map((element) => {
    let newElt = Object.assign({}, element);
    return newElt;
});
```

Comment: [{
         flag: true
         note: "asdasd"
         id: "we"
         name: "tt1"
         list: [{
            "id" : 1,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
            },
            {
            "id" : 2,
            "detail" : "asdasda"
         }]

Comment: after your changes im getting both the id objects i.e id = 1 and id = 2

Comment: This is strange!! Just give it a go again! If doesn't work, please provide the plnkr to reproduce, thanks.

Comment: Have a look    :-------        https://plnkr.co/edit/7rb8iwZHIsnZIXL56d88?p=preview